# Functional Derivative of $\dfrac{\delta^2 I[f^3]}{\delta f(x_0)\delta f(x_1)}$

Tags: derivatives, functional-calculus

I'm looking for some help in functional differentiation. I am self-studying Lancaster & Blundell, and the question below came up. I took a look at the solutions but they were confusing to me and skipped steps. Any help would be appreciated!

Find the functional derivative of $$\dfrac{\delta^2 I[f^3]}{\delta f(x_0)\delta f(x_1)}$$

Where $$I[f]=\int^1_{-1} f(x) dx$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: On Math Stack Exchange, we like to see people's attempts to solve the problem. Also, can you write down or take a picture of the confusing solutions from the book?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.